# Como fazer um UPDATE automático após um INSERT em tabelas sem FK no Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

O banco de dados simula um departamento de trânsito (similar ao Detran). Eu gostaria de implementar um recurso em que: assim que fosse cadastrada uma nova `multa`, o sistema automaticamente adicionaria os pontos dessa nova multa na `cnh` do condutor.
Entretanto, a tabela `multa` **não se comunica** diretamente com a tabela `cnh`. `multa` é referenciada na tabela `registro` por uma FK, e `registro` possui um FK da tabela `cnh`.

Minhas tabelas estão arranjadas deste jeito:

```
CREATE TABLE multa (
  numero_auto INT NOT NULL, -- tabela de auto não é importante nesse caso
  pontuacao INT NOT NULL,
  validade DATE NOT NULL,
  situacao_pgto VARCHAR(1),
  gravidade VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT pk_multa PRIMARY KEY (numero_auto),
  CONSTRAINT fk_auto  FOREIGN KEY (numero_auto) REFERENCES auto(numero_auto)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE registro (
  numero_auto INT NOT NULL, -- fk de multa
  placa VARCHAR(7), -- tabela de veículo não é importante para este caso
  numero_cnh INT, -- fk de cnh
  CONSTRAINT pk_registro PRIMARY KEY (placa, numero_cnh),
  CONSTRAINT fk_auto FOREIGN KEY (numero auto) REFERENCES multa(numero_auto)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_veiculo FOREIGN KEY (placa) REFERENCES veiculo(placa)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_cnh FOREIGN KEY (numero_cnh) REFERENCES cnh(numero_cnh)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE cnh (
  numero_cnh SERIAL,
  validade DATE NOT NULL,
  pontos INT,
  data_emissao DATE NOT NULL,
  categoria VARCHAR(1)
  cpf VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, -- tabela de usuario não é importante para este caso
  CONSTRAINT pk_cnh PRIMARY KEY (numero_cnh),
  CONSTRAINT uq_numero_cnh UNIQUE (cpf, numero_cnh),
  CONSTRAINT fk_usuario FOREIGN KEY(cpf) REFERENCES usuario(cpf)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

O que eu desejo fazer é o seguinte: Sempre que for adicionada uma nova `multa`, o sistema deve verificar a qual `cnh` aquela multa pertence e alterar a coluna "pontos" daquele `cnh` para acrescer neste valor a pontuação da nova `multa`.
Até então eu havia tentado resolver esse problema com um `TRIGGER`. Apesar de não estar dando certo, este era o código:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_pontos_cnh() RETURNS trigger AS $add_pontos$
  BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN                 -- caso a pontuação não se altere não é necessário alterar cnh
      IF OLD.pontuacao <> NEW.pontuacao THEN 
        UPDATE cnh SET pontos = cnh.pontos - OLD.pontuacao + NEW.pontuacao  -- retira-se a pontuacao antiga e soma-se a nova
                   FROM multa JOIN registro USING (numero_auto)
                   WHERE cnh.numero_cnh = registro.numero_cnh
                         AND NEW.numero_auto = multa.numero_auto;
        RETURN NEW;
      END IF;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
      UPDATE cnh SET pontos = cnh.pontos + NEW.pontuacao
                 FROM multa JOIN registro USING (numero_auto)
                 WHERE cnh.numero_cnh = registro.numero_cnh
                       AND NEW.numero_auto = multa.numero_auto;
      RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
  END;
$add_pontos$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER add_pontos AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON multa
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_pontos_cnh();
```

O código compila sem erros, mas ao dar `INSERT` em multa, o valor de "pontos" na `cnh` não se altera.

Segue o esquemático do problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é que você está utilizando a cláusula JOIN no comando UPDATE. Consulte a documentação e não utilize a expressão JOIN, utilize apenas a cláusula FROM e a condição.

Comment: Então, mas como eu vou usar somente o FROM e uma condição sendo que multa e CNH não estão relacionados? Como eu escreveria a condição?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça como o exemplo abaixo:

```
UPDATE cnh SET pontos = cnh.pontos - OLD.pontuacao + NEW.pontuacao
                   FROM multa, registro
                   WHERE cnh.numero_cnh = registro.numero_cnh
                     AND multa.numero_auto = registro.numero_auto
                     AND NEW.numero_auto = multa.numero_auto;
```